# Get file hash in specific changeset in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

**Is there a way to get file hash in a specific changeset/revision in Mercurial?**

Similar to `svn proplist` command in Subversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, since for mercurial the atomic unit is the changeset, not a single file (and rightly so!).

On the other hand, you can use `hg cat` and pipe to any hash utility as follows

```
$ hg cat -r REV FILE | md5
$ hg cat -r REV FILE | shasum
...
```

But again, are you sure focusing on one file (as opposed to the changeset) is the right approach?

Comment: Definitely, Mercurial hashes changesets, not files.

Comment: Yes I know what I am doing, I have to analyze and match files according to their hash.